vite npm run dev failing to detect non-existent names
npm run dev fails to complain about obviously missing names.
Steps to reproduce:

create a React / TypeScript application "foobar" using:

$ npm create vite@latest Need to install the following packages:
create-vite@5.5.2 Ok to proceed? (y) y ✔ Project name: … foobar ✔
Select a framework: › React ✔ Select a variant: › TypeScript


cd into the project and install packages



cd foobar && npm i


edit file src/main.tsx and add a non-existent function call like so:
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'

does_not_exist();

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)



Result:
npm run dev fails to complain about the missing does_not_exist function. npm run build detects it. However I'd like to be using npm run dev during development as it supports recompile on file changes.

I installed vite-plugin-checker:
npm i --D vite-plugin-checker

… and updated my vite.config.ts accordingly:
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    checker({
      typescript: true
    })
  ],
  ...

As a result of the above now errors are detected and the code recompiles whenever a file is saved.
